# Custom Dialog Edittext text can't be changed on samsung

Tags: android

Well it is quite strange issue, I am not sure what may have been causing this issue.

I have an edittext in the custom dialog now when I enter text in this edittext it goes fine, but when I try to click on the text and edit the text it won't let me do it.

Although it works on some of my devices but not for any of my samsung devices.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_patch"
    android:id="@+id/dialogBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whtlbl"
        style="@style/buttons"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Send Message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp" />





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/whtlbl"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/optionLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messageBox"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox2"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        style="@style/buttons"      
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/optionLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/send" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check logcat at the time of checking the samsung device

Comment: sure I am posting it in a minute

Comment: nothing suspicious there just stopSelectionActionMode message mostly along with the my logs

Answer (score 0):

```
you should create popup window in listener.

like :

 imgEditOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lnPopupMain = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_route_edit, null);
                float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 250, activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                popupEditRoute = new PopupWindow(lnPopupMain, (int)width, (int)height, true);
                popupEditRoute.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popupEditRoute.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupEditRoute.showAtLocation(lnPopupMain, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 10);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what difference does it make, if I create it in a listener or create a seperate class for it.